# Android - adView on top of videoView issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am updating an old project from eclipse to Android studio. In the process I also updated Admob. I have a video view, adview and linear layout above it that toggles when video view is touched. This used to work fine in the previous version. However there is an odd behaviour in the new version of the app.

I see 1px of the ad at the bottom, and the ad only shows up once I have touched the screen, upon second touch, then the linear layout contents show up. The ad used to show up right away on top...

Can anyone please help me understand what I am doing wrong? Thank-you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.me.app.Main">

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/video1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ControlLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:visibility="invisible">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onEvent1"
        android:text="item1" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:onClick="onEvent2"
        android:text="item2" />
</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    />
```

Relevant code in the class:

```
menuView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ControlLayout);

    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video1);
    videoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (menuView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                menuView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                menuView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**UPDATE:**
So it turns out that I am still not able to get the adView on top of the video aligned bottom center. Been trying all kinds of things. I even removed all other functionality with all that was left was the videoView and adView. Still does not show up. Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: didnt get your issue

Answer (score 0):

Let's look into your xml code.
First you have added a ***Videoview*** fill parent in your xml
Actually it mean your complete area will cover with this view also it depend on 
your video resolution. 
It may be possible video aspect ration will be high and ad mob view will hide 
in your layout.

**Solution :**
Give your video view Wrap content or specific size.

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/video1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but doesn't quite work way it should. The video now is small and in top left, but ad shows ok. The video should be full screen and ad on top...

Comment: Not sure what you mean, wrap it all with SurfaceView?